# Split a sentence based off two conditions

Tags: java, python

if the input is given as follows:

```
abc "def abc" mno pqr "est mnr"
```

the output should be as follows:

```
abc 
def abc
mno
pqr
est mnr
```

Comment: Are you using Java or Python?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: any language is fine. Its just that i'm not able to crack the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python option using `re.findall`:

```
inp = 'abc "def abc" mno pqr "est mnr"'
parts = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)".*?"(?!\S)|\b\w+\b', inp)
parts = map(lambda x : re.sub(r'"(.*)"', '\\1', x), parts)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['abc', 'def abc', 'mno', 'pqr', 'est mnr']
```

Note that the second `map` step is required to remove double quotes, from those matches which were quoted terms.